# Use BoolResult in pythonQt

Tags: python, c++, qt, pythonqt

in C++ BoolResult is casted to a pointer:

```
bool ok;
int i = QInputDialog::getInt(this, tr("QInputDialog::getInteger()"),
                             tr("Percentage:"), 25, 0, 100, 1, &ok);
if (ok)
    integerLabel->setText(tr("%1%").arg(i));
```

How would one retrieve the "ok" bool in pyQt/pythonQt?

It tried the following which won't work:

```
from PythonQt.QtGui import QInputDialog, QWidget
from PythonQt.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PythonQt import BoolResult
...
x = QWidget()
x.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
ok = BoolResult()
i = QInputDialog.getInt(x, "test", "hallo", 1000, None, None, None, ok)
print("ok:", ok)
print("i:", i)
print("i:", i)
```

which results in

```
2/24/2018 17:49:42  pyTSon.PluginHost.onMenuItemEvent   Error   Error calling onMenuItemEvent of python plugin Auto Channel Commander: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/blusc/AppData/Roaming/TS3Client/plugins/pyTSon/scripts\pluginhost.py", line 663, in onMenuItemEvent
    plugin.onMenuItemEvent(schid, atype, locid, selectedItemID)
  File "C:/Users/blusc/AppData/Roaming/TS3Client/plugins/pyTSon/scripts\autoCommander\__init__.py", line 64, in onMenuItemEvent
    i = QInputDialog.getInt(x, "test", "hallo", 1000, None, None, None, ok)
ValueError: Could not find matching overload for given arguments:
(QWidget(0x2759aa87560) , 'test', 'hallo', 1000, None, None, None, BoolResult(False))
 The following slots are available:
static getInt(QWidget parent, QString title, QString label, int value, int minValue, int maxValue, int step, PythonQt.BoolResult ok, Qt::WindowFlags flags) -> int
static getInt(QWidget parent, QString title, QString label, int value, int minValue, int maxValue, int step, PythonQt.BoolResult ok) -> int
static getInt(QWidget parent, QString title, QString label, int value, int minValue, int maxValue, int step) -> int
static getInt(QWidget parent, QString title, QString label, int value, int minValue, int maxValue) -> int
static getInt(QWidget parent, QString title, QString label, int value, int minValue) -> int
static getInt(QWidget parent, QString title, QString label, int value) -> int
static getInt(QWidget parent, QString title, QString label) -> int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is that you must assign appropriate values and you should not use `None`, for example if we see the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html#getInt) of Qt:

> **int QInputDialog::getInt(QWidget *parent, const QString &title, const QString &label, int value = 0, int min = -2147483647, int max = 2147483647, int step = 1, bool *ok = Q_NULLPTR, Qt::WindowFlags flags = Qt::WindowFlags())**

so a possible solution is to copy these values:

```
ok = BoolResult()
i = QInputDialog.getInt(push1, "test", "hallo", 1000, -2147483647, 2147483647, 1, ok)
print("ok:", ok)
print("i:", i)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I believed that `None` was passing the default :)